# Deconfiguration android development environment with eclipse. Many issues occurs simultaneously

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Below I explain the facts in order:

- Less than an hour ago I was developing in the Eclipse with android SDK without any problem.
- I close Eclipse SDK and turn off the computer
- After an hour I start my computer, open Eclipse and have appeared
  multiple problems that I describe below.

To solve these problems I have tried cleaning all projects (projects>clean) and restarting Eclipse/PC. I have not gotten any results.

Problems:

- When I start eclipse opens a window popup : "Could not find C:\User\Admin\Android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe!"
- In google-play-services_lib (Google library) project in UnusedStub.java in constructor declaration "Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"
- In all Android projects that I'm developing : in R reference, example: "setContentView(**R**.layout.mylist);": "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Any idea which has caused these problems simultaneously and how to fix it?

Comment: Does `C:\User\Admin\Android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe` exist?

Comment: In C:\Users\Admin\android-sdks\tools I have emulator-arm.exe, emulator-mips.exe and emulator-x86.exe but not emulator.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed all problems simply updating all the eclipse plugings. (Help>Check for updates)